# What is the best way to list languages or tags you are avoiding or would like to exclude?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Often in my searches or in my questioning I end with answers that involve a language, library or other form of code that I must avoid using in a current project.

**Example:** I will be writing some custom JavaScript and get several answers that use jQuery, but the nature of the project doesn't allow me to use jQuery or I'm simply trying to avoid using it.

Is it best to write it in the title (no jQuery) or at the beginning of the question in bold "**JavaScript Only (no jQuery)**"

I know there's probably lots of ways this could be handled, but is there a standard, best practice, or a community preference that has been noticed?

Comment: Why would you try to *avoid* jQuery? You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: Ha, no I love jQuery too! I have some occasional projects that require straight JavaScript - a requirement that is placed on me, but not preferred.

Comment: Sorry, its a meme: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492

Comment: lol nice - worthy of an upvote

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do it. Some of them are:

1. Add in the question post **with bold text**. I always do that to highlight my question after all the code. It works, and helps people notice the important points easily
2. Add the text in parentheses after your title.
3. Not including the tag you don't want the answer in. (obviously)

However, the first option would be preferable[personal opinion though] and help to keep the post titles saner.

Comment: Ya this seems to be what I notice most commonly. I wish there were negative tags, but then I can see why that still wouldn't be as effective as simply explaining it at the top where the question is.